# Can I change the progress bar in a webview to a progress circle?

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, loading, geometry

This is my code :

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

final Activity activity = this;

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             activity.setTitle("Loading...");
             activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100)
                   activity.setTitle("My title");
             }
});

mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

I want to change the progress style to a circle.

How to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); // Request progress circle
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); // Show progress circle

WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

final Activity activity = this;

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             activity.setTitle("Loading...");
             activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100)
                   setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); // Hide progress circle when page loaded
                   activity.setTitle("My title");
             }
});

mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATUREPROGRESS, Window.PROGRESSVISIBILITY_ON);
```